# Maven update site creation and deployment

Tags: maven, deployment, tycho

I am trying to build an update site for my plugins built with maven. I have a site project with following entry;

```
<packaging>eclipse-update-site</packaging>
```

I get the site.zip in the end containing only site.xml in it even though within target/site I have all the folders i.e features/*.jar, plugin/*.jar, artefacts.jar, content.jar and site.xml.

Secondly I would like to upload the site.zip (with all the contents) on to the FTP site (delete the old version on remote machine and extract this new zip for DEV, for version releases I would like to keep the older releases)

Could you please point me to right direction as I am new to this whole thing.

Thanks

--

Sjunejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

packaging type eclipse-update-site is deprecated, use eclipse-repository instead which will create a repository zip by default.
For details see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card#Update_Site

Comment: that worked, just once clarification i.e. in the archive (*.zip) file it did not package the category.xml? how can I add this? Also now I have this zip. could you please also point me on what is the best of updating the actual repository i.e. FTP site. I can use wagon-ftp to upload but how to replace the artefacts already there and versions etc.

Comment: Category.xml information should be rolled into the generated content.xml/jar and artifacts.xml/jar files. This file does not need to exist separately in the resulting p2 repository.

Comment: Thanks Simon, how about the versioning, or in other words I have a zip which I can upload to my FTP site, but can I extract remotely the zip on my release site also how would user will see that there are other versions available?